# Error in Many to one relation

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

My Organization entity

```
@Entity
public class Organization implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key key;
private String name;
private String type;
private byte image;
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name="ORGANIZATION_ID") 
private List<User> admin;
```

My User entity

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key key;    
private String score;
private boolean online;
private String resume;
public Status status;
public enum Status {
    ACTIVE, INACTIVE, VERIFIED, NOT_VERIFIED , BANNED
};

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name="ORGANIZATION_ID") 
private Organization organization;
@Persistent
private User_personal user_p;

public User_personal getUser_personal(){

    return user_p;
}

public void setUser_personal(User_personal user_p) {
    this.user_p = user_p;
}
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
private List<Project> projects;
```

I got the one-Many relation between User and Projects correctly but not working for User and Organization(many-one).I am getting error like this

```
 WARNING: /OrganizationServlet
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Detected attempt to establish 
 Organization(no-id-yet) as the parent of User(4793870697103360) but the 
 entity identified by User(4793870697103360) has already been persisted 
 without a parent.  A parent cannot be established or changed once an object 
 has been persisted.at...

 showing error at em.getTransaction().commit();.
```

My servlet is

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
    response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HashMap<String,String> map = Request_to_map.getBody(request);       
    boolean validToken = JWT.parseJWT(request.getHeader("Access-token") 
   ,map.get("email"));
    JsonObject output = new JsonObject();
    List<User> organization_admin = new ArrayList<User>();
    if(validToken == true){
        EntityManager em;
        em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
        String organizationName = map.get("name");
        String type = map.get("type");
        byte image = 0;
        if(map.get("image")!=null)
        {
            image = Byte.valueOf(map.get("image"));
        }
        String email = map.get("email");

 if(organizationName==null||type==null||email==null||map.get("image")==null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("please fill required 
            details");
        }
        try{
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            User user = User.find(email, em);
            if(user!=null)
            {
                Organization.org_status status= org_status.ACTIVE;
                Organization organization = new 
                Organization(organizationName, type,image,status);
                user.setOrganization(organization);
                organization_admin  = organization.getAdmin();
                if(organization_admin  == null)
                {
                    organization_admin = new ArrayList<User>();
                }
                organization_admin .add(user);
                organization.setAdmin(organization_admin);          
                em.persist(organization);   
                em.persist(user);   
                output.addProperty("message", "done");
                em.getTransaction().commit();
            }
            else
                output.addProperty("message","No such User found.Please 
               check details provided");    
        }
        finally{
            if(em.getTransaction().isActive())
                em.getTransaction().rollback();
    //      em.close();
        }
    }
    else
        output.addProperty(Constants.MESSAGE,  
         Constants.TokenNotAuthenticated);

        response.setContentType("application/Json");
        response.getWriter().println(output);
}
```

Can anyone help me in getting this? When user is created I am getting ORGANIZATION_ID as a column but cant create entity of organization.I dont think joins are to be used as GAE doesn't allow it.

Comment: From what I remember, AppEngine Datastore is utterly ugly and tried to insist on these entity group things, with owners, but in v2.0 of Google's plugin they allowed "Unowned Relationships". Suggest that you use unowned relationships if using JPA because that is what best matches the model that JPA pushes (i.e normal relations between objects)

Comment: @Niel thanks for the reply:) I tried many things and finally am very much confused of wheher i am using jpa or jdo or whatever.Can you help me in getting the annotations right?

Comment: You have an EntityManager ... hence you're using JPA. If you don't understand such things then go back to documentation and the JPA spec. Why you would use appengine-datastore on JPA is beyond my comprehension though

Comment: cant we use?neil?

Comment: @sai183 just to clear your confusion: you're using a JDO implementation pretending to be a JPA implementation so that you could benefit from object-relational mapping on a datastore that is not relational. Have a good day

Comment: @crizzis!! can I continue or is this wrong?I have been able to create User entity and also one-one with user_personal and also one_many with user_projects but cant do many to one with company

Comment: I think the warning on the top of this page:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2 fully explains my point

Comment: So I have to leave app-engine+datanuclues+JPA/JDO  and shift to mysql+hibernate+JPA?

Comment: Unowned relationship worked for me :))but i am having problem in type conversion from String to Key.Can anyone help me?